# Which contentType should I use for requests with access_token?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I fount out that "Content-type" - "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" should be used with oauth2.
Is it necessary to use this contentType always or only when requesting for access_token, or using refresh_token?

So my question is, which content type I should use for sending regular POST, GET, PUT requests from front-end. If I can use application/json for these requests, or ALL the time I should use x-www-form-urlencoded...
Thank you for advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use other *Content-type* like *application/json* for your requests from the FE. Just make sure you have the *Authorization* header in those requests.
A good starting guide on oauth https://aaronparecki.com/oauth-2-simplified/